# Is it possible to crop the bottom of an element with a subtle curve?

Tags: css, overlay, z-index, crop, curve

I want to be able to cut off the bottom of a large div (about 2000px) with a curve about 60px deep. Currently I have implemented this by placing a transparent image over the top which cuts it off. The only problem is that some elements on the main div are inaccessible because they are behind the curve overlay.

I really doubt this is possible, even in CSS3, but if anyone has any ideas please share.

Also, if there is a way I can arrange the current setup to allow elements in the main div which are behind the curve to be clicked then that would be just as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply a border radius to the very bottom...

```
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 50px;
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2g6sB/).

Experiment with the radius' value to get the desired effect.

Alternatively, you could prevent the element being used currently from blocking the pointer with...

```
pointer-events: none;
```